# trouble with table row selection in Firefox 68.0 and Safari 12.1.1 using RemoteWebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm having trouble with table row selection using the Firefox and Safari RemoteWebDrivers.

The tables are coded so a single click on a row selects the row and a double-click opens a form to edit the table entry (if the entry is editable).

I need to use a single click to select a row and shift-click to select multiple contiguous rows of the table. I have a solution that works for Chrome and Edge but doesn't work for Firefox or Safari. I'd really like a universal solution, but I can accommodate special cases for particular browsers. Lord knows, I have plenty of those already. :-(

Versions:
Firefox: 68.0
GeckoDriver 24.0
Running on Windows 8.1 64-bit

Safari: 12.1.1
Running on High Sierra 10.13.6

Code for clicking looks like this (element is the \ element):

```
Wait.Until(d => element.Enabled);
if (Browser == BROWSERS.SAFARI)
{
    IJavaScriptExecutor executor = Driver;
    executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].focus();", element);
    executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
 }
 else
 {
    element.Click(); // This only works intermittently on Safari 
 }
```

Code for shift click looks like this (startRow and endRow are  elements):

```
    Actions action = new Actions(wd.Driver);
    action.Click(startRow).KeyDown(Keys.Shift).Click(endRow).KeyUp(Keys.Shift).Perform();
```

Firefox Issues:

1. Single click doesn't work. (see code above)

Expected: The row that gets clicked is selected. 
Actual: It throws an ElementNotInteractableException.

2. Shift-click to select multiple rows acts like a double-click.

I get the start and end row elements for my range then execute the shift-click code shown above.

Expected: All rows between startRow and endRow inclusive are selected and nothing else occurs. 
Actual: All rows between startRow and endRow inclusive are selected but the form for editing the startRow entry also opens. 
Interestingly, it always opens the form for startRow, regardless of whether I click first on endRow then startRow or vice versa.

Safari Issue: 
The Shift-click code shown above causes Safari to close with a message: "Safari quit unexpectedly." The report shows:

```
10  com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x000000010699b812 WTF::RunLoop::performWork(void*) + 34
11  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff41a12581 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
12  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff41aca8ac __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 108
13  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff419f5530 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 208
14  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff419f49ad __CFRunLoopRun + 1293
15  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff419f4207 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 487
16  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff40cd4d96 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 286
17  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff40cd4b06 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 613
18  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff40cd4884 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff3ef84a73 _DPSNextEvent + 2085
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff3f71ae34 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 3044
21  com.apple.Safari.framework      0x00000001059f7bf0 -[BrowserApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 273
22  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff3ef79885 -[NSApplication run] + 764
23  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff3ef48a72 NSApplicationMain + 804
24  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff699bd015 start + 1
```

Which isn't very informative to me (although I can identify with the WTF part).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've "solved" the shift-click problems by abandoning actions altogether and just using javascript.

```
public void ShiftClick(IWebElement control)
{
   string shiftClickScript = "var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');" +
        "evt.initMouseEvent('click',true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, true, false, 0, null);" +
        "arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evt);";
   ((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript(shiftClickScript, control);
}
```

I still have no idea why the Actions approach doesn't work...